# What is wrong with my SQLite update query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

My SQLite update query doesn't work, but returns no error...

```
public void updateData(String stickerPackTitle, String installed) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_INSTALLED, installed);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "' " + COL_PACK_NAME + " = " + stickerPackTitle + " '", null);
    }
```

Comment: why the  `' COL_PACK_NAME = value '` and not `COL_PACK_NAME = 'value'` ?

Comment: I don't see that but when I changed this, there is no changes...  Doesn't work again.

Comment: you should add the creation query for the table at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the right method to use update query in SQLite. You should keep where clause and your where arguments in different parameters. And yes, **don't forgot to close the database connection.**

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COL_PACK_NAME + " =?", new String[] stickerPackTitle});
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace update line with this:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv,  COL_PACK_NAME + " = '" + stickerPackTitle + "'", null);
```

Comment: try this: db.execSQL("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET " + COL_INSTALLED + " = '" + installed + "' WHERE " + COL_PACK_NAME + " = '" + stickerPackTitle + "'");

Comment: `code` android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "installed_items": syntax error (code 1): `code`

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of code :

```
public void update_PrimaryOffer(PrimaryOffer p)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("businessId", p.getBusinessId());
        contentValues.put("primaryOfferDiscount", p.getPrimaryOfferDiscount());
        contentValues.put("offerImage", p.getOfferName());
        contentValues.put("businessType", p.getBusinessType());
        contentValues.put("businessName", p.getBusinessName());
        contentValues.put("businessInformation", p.getBusinessInformation());
        contentValues.put("businessImage", p.getBusinessImage());
        contentValues.put("offerName", p.getOfferName());
        contentValues.put("offerAddress", p.getOfferAddress());
        contentValues.put("phoneNumber", p.getPhoneNumber());
        contentValues.put("originalPrice", p.getOriginalPrice());
        contentValues.put("expiryDate", p.getExpiryDate());
        contentValues.put("latitude", p.getLatitude());
        contentValues.put("longitude", p.getLongitude());
        contentValues.put("likeStatus", p.getLikeStatus());
        contentValues.put("favoriteStatus", p.getFavoriteStatus());
        contentValues.put("likeCount", p.getLikeCount());
//      contentValues.put("DateTime", p.getDateTime());


        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_RECENT_PRIMARY_OFFER+";", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int ii = sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_RECENT_PRIMARY_OFFER, contentValues, "businessId="+ p.getBusinessId(),null);
                System.out.println("SQLITE UPDATE SCHEDULER---->" + ii);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        cursor.close();


    }
```